# PHP, URL rewriting with htaccess, and Microsoft IIS Url Rewriting

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I am used to working with Apache servers, so when mod_rewrite is enabled, I can create an htaccess file and use URL rewriting.

Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now I've built this site that uses this URL rewriting module but I have come to learn that it is a Microsoft server. Can I use my htaccess file? Is there something I need to change to get it to work? How can I tell if URL rewriting is set up on the Microsoft server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your configuration as is, in [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter (IIRF)](http://iirf.codeplex.com).

IIRF is free, open-source.

Comment: Just looked into this today and I was unable to run the installer on Win2012, so it *might* not work on newer systems.

Answer (score 10):

If you use IIS 7 then you can use IIS URL Rewrite Module, that has an ["Import Rules" feature](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/) that can be used to translate mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL rewrite format. These particular rewrite rules will not translate because the RewriteCond uses the "-s" and "-l" flags which check if the requested URL corresponds to a non-zero size file or to a symbolic link on a file system. If your application does not use any symbolic links then you can safely replace these conditions with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
```

and then convert the rules by using IIS URL Rewrite UI. That will result in these rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"  />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"  />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4):

The .htaccess file is an Apache convention for providing end-user access to Apache configuration, so you're not going to be able to use it as a drop in replacement on an IIS (Microsoft) server.  You **would** be able to use it if you were running Apache on Windows.

IIS7 has a [URL rewriting module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite) that offers support for rewriting URLs.  There's also the [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) product which does the same for previous versions of IIS.  You'll likely need some level of administrative permissions on the server to use either of these modules (i.e., no htaccess-like mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

You may use your above config as is in ISAPI_Rewrite 3 or [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) products.