# Search-Engine Friendly URLs with IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, seo, search-engine

I am working on building a search-engine friendly CMS. I know that perhaps one of the biggest keys to having and SEO site is to have search-engine friendly URLs. So having a link like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/details/page1
```

will result in much better rankings than one like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?pageID=37
```

I know that to create URLs like the first one, I have one of two options:

- use a web technology, in this case PHP, to create a directory structure
- leverage IIS to have these SEO URLs passed to PHP for proper processing

As far as the PHP goes, I'm pretty comfortable with anything. However,  I think the first option would be more difficult to maintain.

I don't have any experience with IIS (my experience is limited to Apache), but I am required to use IIS for this client for which I am building this CMS, since they have a server running PHP on IIS 6. Could someone show me to write an IIS 6 equivalent of an .htaccess file, which will:

- silently direct SEO URLs to a processor script
- not redirect if the requested URL is an actual directory on the server

This application will be deployed on the client's server, and I will not have root access to it at any point.

Is there a better way than the way I am trying it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IIS 6 I think your best bet is to use [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/). It's a native filter for IIS that enables configurable URL rewriting using a mostly-compatible .htaccess syntax.

It's compatible with any platform that IIS can serve (.NET, ASP, PHP, Ruby, etc), it's well-maintained and documented.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, this application will be deployed on the client's server, which I will not have root access to.

Comment: @spryno724 : you'll need some access to the server's IIS whether you use IIRF or not. You could create a simple script that installs IIRF on IIS. If you don't use IIRF you'll still need to access IIS config to do a wildcard extension map to the PHP ISAPI.

Comment: Hmm... having no background with IIS I'm still a bit lost. With an Apache server, I can simply create an .htaccess file in the folder (and also sub-folders) which I want it to affect. I can simply check if the `mod_rewrite` module is installed, and, if so, I'm set to go! I have WebDAV access to the project's root folder on the server. Is that all that I need to utilize IIRF?

Comment: @spryno724 : nope, with IIS 6 you'll need access to IIS config. With IIS 7 it would be different, but IIS 6 is pretty limited about this.

Comment: @spryno724 : related question (pretty much a duplicate actually): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029431/php-url-rewriting-with-htaccess-and-microsoft-iis-url-rewriting

Comment: Thank you for your time Mauricio. Points up and answer accepted.