# url rewrite .htacces IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

Installed Wordpress on an IIS sever and It is working fine; but, I installed the XML Sitemaps plugin and activated but it deactivate automatically.   A message appear saying that "XML Sitemaps is not active on your site. Please make the following file and folder writable by the server:
.htaccess (chmod 666)
wp-content (chmod 777)".  The "wp-content" is writable, now; but the ".htaccess" is not.  I contact the server administrators and said that I need do a url rewrite.  I need help with this!!!!!

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.cl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=htaccess%20url%20rewrite)

Comment: @Vertig0 I already did a search, but I did not find a good article.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link it may be help you for url rewrite

**[Importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)**

Also check this link **[PHP, URL rewriting with htaccess, and Microsoft IIS Url Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029431/php-url-rewriting-with-htaccess-and-microsoft-iis-url-rewriting)**

Comment: @Vertig0 My problem is I do not know which rule(s) I need to write or where.  I am starting to get my feet wet; so I need guidance.